# Trouble building mean-cli; how to debug?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm, mean-stack

I'm trying to build mongoose, and the npm build is failing.  I have npm 2.11.2, node 0.10.38, and mongodb 3.0.4.

Here's the install log:

```
username@hostname:~$ npm install -g mean-cli
> mean-cli@0.10.14 preinstall /home/username/node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/mean-cli
> node ./scripts/preinstall
npm WARN deprecated json-file-plus@2.0.0: Before v3.0.0, errors in fs.writeFile would not be propagated
> mean-health@0.1.7 postinstall /home/username/node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mean-health
> node ./postinstall.js
> kerberos@0.0.12 install /home/username/node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/home/username/node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
kerberos.target.mk:90: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o' failed
make: Leaving directory '/home/username/node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos/build'
npm WARN installMany nopt was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree
...
npm WARN installMany rimraf was bundled with node-pre-gyp@0.6.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree

> bson-ext@0.1.10 install /home/username/node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext
> (node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build) || (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

sh: 1: node-pre-gyp: not found
make: Entering directory '/home/username/node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bson/ext/bson.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bson.node
  COPY Release/bson.node
make: Leaving directory '/home/username/node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/bson/node_modules/bson-ext/build'
/home/username/node_modules_global/bin/mean-init -> /home/username/node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean-init
/home/username/node_modules_global/bin/mean -> /home/username/node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/mean-cli/bin/mean
...
mean-cli@0.10.14 /home/username/node_modules_global/lib/node_modules/mean-cli
├── opener@1.4.1
...
```

I've tried installing kerberos; I still get the error

```
user@machine:~/node-test$ npm install kerberos
|
> kerberos@0.0.12 install /home/user/node-test/node_modules/kerberos
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory '/home/user/node-test/node_modules/kerberos/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o
kerberos.target.mk:90: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/kerberos/lib/kerberos.o' failed
make: Leaving directory '/home/user/node-test/node_modules/kerberos/build'
kerberos@0.0.12 node_modules/kerberos
└── nan@1.8.4
```

I've tried installing node-gyp; it succeeds but does not help.

Comment: Those aren't errors, your installations were successful. If an installation ends with an error it will look like this: `npm ERR! not ok code 0`

Comment: How can kerberos have succeeded if kerberos.o failed?  And why did it fail?  Why is it only telling us that the recipe failed, giving no error message?